# Is there any way to avoid creation of new object while refereshing page in django?

Tags: django

i have a function which add question and answers to a model. When i submit it if form is valid, save it redirect it to another view which will display the questions and answers. Problem arrives when i reload that page, a another object will created again and displayed? how that possible?

views.py
for adding the question and answer

```
if request.method == 'POST':
       form = FaqForm(request.POST)
       faq_formset = FaqFormset(request.POST ,prefix='faq_formset')
       if form.is_valid() and faq_formset.is_valid():
            for ch in faq_formset:
                course = ch.cleaned_data.get('course')
                ques = ch.cleaned_data.get('ques')
                ans = ch.cleaned_data.get('ans')
                Faq(
                    course=course,
                    ques=ques,
                    ans=ans,
                ).save()        
       return faq(request)
```

for displaying it:

```
def faq(request):
    faq = Faq.objects.all()
    lms_faculty = request.session['lms_faculty']
    context = {
        'dash_title' : 'View FAQ',
        'heading' : 'FAQ',
        'lms_faculty' : lms_faculty,
        'faq' : faq,
    }
    return render(request, 'lmsadmin/view_faq.html', context)
```

views.py
what i tried initially

```
if request.method == 'POST':
       form = FaqForm(request.POST)
       faq_formset = FaqFormset(request.POST ,prefix='faq_formset')
       if form.is_valid() and faq_formset.is_valid():
            for ch in faq_formset:
                course = ch.cleaned_data.get('course')
                ques = ch.cleaned_data.get('ques')
                ans = ch.cleaned_data.get('ans')
                Faq(
                    course=course,
                    ques=ques,
                    ans=ans,
                ).save()        
       faq = Faq.objects.all()
       lms_faculty = request.session['lms_faculty']
        context = {
            'dash_title' : 'View FAQ',
            'heading' : 'FAQ',
            'lms_faculty' : lms_faculty,
            'faq' : faq,
        }
        return render(request, 'lmsadmin/view_faq.html', context)
```

On reload the web page i don't want to create duplicate object of existing object. Please help me, i have used this type in other areas also. Please correct me.

Comment: Where's your redirect...?

Comment: Do i need to use redirect? how's that ?i'm new to django . i usually do like this, 
return render(request, 'lmsadmin/view_faq.html', context).

Comment: You need to use redirect to avoid post actions being repeated like you're seeing (you'll also see similar problems if you use the back forward buttons etc.)

Comment: return HttpResponseRedirect('view_name') ? like this

Comment: Thank you so much@thebjorn it worked. i used return redirect(reverse('app:view_name'))

Answer (score 0):

To redirect you should

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
...
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
```